# Detect NFC tag through all the activities

Tags: android, nfc

I'm working on Android NFC based application with requirement of continuously read/write data to SLIX-2(ICode) tag from any activity.

As of now, application starts to initialize NFCManager which does most of the heavy lifting for Tag detection, continuously polling for presence check, read & write data.

BaseActivity does initialization of ANFCManager with other required work such as pending restart Intent, check nfc adapter, enableForegroundDispatch, ...

```
private fun initField() {
  mNfcManager = ANfcManager(this)
}

private fun createPendingRestartIntent() {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, Intent(this, javaClass)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0
        )
    }

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    try {
        if(mNfcManager.checkNfcPowerStatus()) // NfcAdapter enabled or not
            setReadyToHandleTag()
        else Log.w(TAG, "Nfc is not supported or disabled.") 

    } catch (e: AcmNfcManager.NfcNotEnabledException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Nfc not enabled", e)
    }
}

private fun setReadyToHandleTag() {

    try {
        TECHLISTS = arrayOf(arrayOf(IsoDep::class.java.name), arrayOf(NfcV::class.java.name),
            arrayOf(NfcA::class.java.name), arrayOf(NfcB::class.java.name),
            arrayOf(NfcF::class.java.name),arrayOf(Ndef::class.java.name),
            arrayOf(NdefFormatable::class.java.name))

        val tagDetected = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        TAGFILTERS = arrayOf(tagDetected)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "TECH or TAG filter no detected!!!" )
    }
    pendingIntent?.let { mNfcManager.enableForegroundDispatch(this, it, TAGFILTERS, TECHLISTS) }
}

 override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    nfcState = mNfcManager.filterIntent(intent)
    dispatchActionOnTag(nfcState)
}

// this abs function will provide the Tag state in the corresponding class
abstract fun dispatchActionOnTag(tag: Boolean)
```

Each Activity has NfcListener for tag detection and will do the read/write using ANfcManager API's. Also to continuously checking the tag presence, using handler with looper internal class inside NFC Manager for presence check.

Here is the function inside ActivityA which trigger **the method after tag detection** as well as  presence check thread,

```
override fun dispatchActionOnTag(tag: Boolean) {
    mNfcStatus = tag
    if (nfcStateListener() != null) {
        nfcStateListener().updateNfcState(tag)
        mNfcManager.startTagCheck() // presence check handler every x sec
    }
}
```

This same function is been repeated(kind of not clean but still works) in each of the activity for tag detection and presence check & based on that read/write data to the Tag.

**Here comes my problem,**

Preconditions :

- Tag in my application(product) is at a fixed location(sticked in a hardware) & is not usually taken out unless there is a tag change.
- There are situations where Tag can be taken out in mostly ActivityB or ActivityC activity will be running, which required to repeat the same callback code in these activities.

Required: 
- When switching from ActvityA-> ActivityB, Tag detection flow is not done(onNewIntent) or TAg is not taken out from proximity and tapped again. **How will I write/read data to the tag?**

ANFCManager,

```
class ANfcManager @Inject constructor(context: Context) {

    private val mContext = context
    private lateinit var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter

    private lateinit var mTag: Tag
    private lateinit var iCodeTag: ICodeSlix2
    private lateinit var icode: ICode

init {

    val readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        mContext,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    if (!readPermission) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            mContext as Activity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 113
        )
    }

    /**
     * initialize background thread for presence check every x seconds.
     */
    val thread = HandlerThread("PresenceCheckThread")
    thread.start()
    mHandler = PresenceHandler(thread.looper)
}

fun enableForegroundDispatch(
    activity: FragmentActivity, intent: PendingIntent,
    filters: Array<IntentFilter>?, techLists: Array<Array<String>>?
) {
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, intent, filters, techLists)
}

fun disableForegroundDispatch(activity: Activity) {
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity)
}

fun filterIntent(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val action = intent.action

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED == action
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED == action
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == action
    ) {

        if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
            mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)!!
            return if (discoverTag()) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Tag detected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            } else {
                ignoreTag()
                false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

/**
 * discover the Tag family.
 */
fun discoverTag(): Boolean {
    icode = getTag(mTag)
    if (ICodeSlix2::class.java.isInstance(icode))
        iCodeTag = icode as ICodeSlix2
    return iCodeTag != null
}

fun checkNfcPowerStatus(): Boolean {
    return checkNfcPowerStatus(mContext)
}

/**
 * Check Nfc status
 */
private fun checkNfcPowerStatus(context: Context?): Boolean {
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context)
    var enabled = false
    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        enabled = nfcAdapter.isEnabled
    }
    return enabled
}

fun writeUpdateBlocks() {
try {
    iCodeTag.connect()
.
. // proprietary code
.
}catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException: ", e)
} catch (e: SmartCardException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.e(TAG, "SmartCardException: ", e)
} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.e(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: ", e)
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.e(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: ", e)
} catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.e(TAG, "IndexOutOfBoundsException: ", e)
} finally {
    iCodeTag.close()
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Required: - When switching from ActvityA-> ActivityB, Tag detection
>   flow is not done(onNewIntent) or TAg is not taken out from proximity
>   and tapped again. How will I write/read data to the tag?

So the Tag object is a Parcelable Object , just pass it from ActivityA to ActivityB, you don't need to re-discover it.

e.g. something like (sorry in Java not Kotlin)
ActivityA

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("TAG", mTag);
startActivity(intent);
```

The in ActivityB `onCreate`

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra("TAG")
// Start doing stuff with the Tag just like if you got it via discovery
// ANfcManager might need a `setTag` method to set it without discovery.
// or allow a Tag be be passed in the ANfcManager constructor
```

Not that I would use `enableForegroundDispatch` for reading and especially writing to Tags as I found it too unreliable, I would recommend `enableReaderMode` but then you can still pass the Tag Object between activities.

Answer (score 0):

It was quick to convert the Manager class as Singleton and rest all remain same.

BaseActivity,

```
fun initField() {
   mNfcManager = ANfcManager.getInstance(this)
}

class ANfcManager private constructor(context: Context){

companion object : SingletonHolder<ANfcManager, Context>(::ANfcManager) {
        val TAG = ANfcManager::class.java.simpleName
    }

   init{
     mContext = context
     .
     .
     .
   }
}
```